# Include input in output print line

Tags: java, format, java.util.scanner

I am trying to get my code to print results out as "21.0 C = 69.80 F" but I can't get it to include the initial celsius input or limit it to the second decimal wihout error codes. This is for homework so I want to know where I'm going wrong, and what I need to add or remove to be able to format my System.out.print

```
public class Celcius2Farenheit {

        /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double celsius, fahrenheit;
        Scanner scanner;
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a temperature in celsius:");
        celsius = scanner.nextDouble();
        fahrenheit = (9.0 / 5.0) * celsius + 32;
        System.out.printf("%.2f"  + fahrenheit);
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `System.out.printf("%.2f C= %.2f F", celsius, fahrenheit);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track using the `printf` method for formatting. However, the format string you provided to `printf` is incomplete.

The `printf` method allows you to specify placeholders in the format string and then provide the arguments to replace those placeholders.

Here's how you can modify your code to get the desired output:

1. The format string should be: `"%.2f C = %.2f F\n"`
2. Provide both `celsius` and `fahrenheit` as arguments to `printf`.

Here's the corrected part of your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Celcius2Farenheit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double celsius, fahrenheit;
        Scanner scanner;
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a temperature in celsius:");
        celsius = scanner.nextDouble();
        fahrenheit = (9.0 / 5.0) * celsius + 32;
        System.out.printf("%.2f C = %.2f F\n", celsius, fahrenheit);
    }
    
}
```

Now, if you enter a value like `21`, it will correctly print: `21.00 C = 69.80 F`.